# jpa eclipselink Exception [EclipseLink-4002]

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, hql

Here is an exception I'm getting:

```
[EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: 
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Vergleiche zwischen 'BIGINT' und 'VARCHAR (UCS_BASIC)' 
werden nicht unterstützt.

Error Code: 30000
Call: SELECT t1.ID, t1.TEXTINFO FROM COORDINATESLOCATION_INFORMATION t0, TEXTINFORMATION t1 
WHERE ((t0.CoordinatesLocation_ID = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.informationList_ID))
bind => [1 parameter bound]
```

When I run my application first (without an empty database) everything works. I easily can manage data in all CRUD functions. Later (after an unspecific time or several requests), the exception appears.

This is a tourist information application. There are authors that create tours. One tour contains many locations. One location contains many information. The associations are realised as compositions.

As I changed every association to eager fetch, the exception appears earlier in the workflow.

Here are the code snippets:

```
    @Entity
    public class CoordinatesLocation implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Information> informationList = new ArrayList<>();
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    }

    @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
    public abstract class Information implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    }

    @Entity
    public class TextInformation extends Information {

    private String textInfo;
    }
```

Plus getter & setter!

Thanks for helping!

Comment: cab91 - can you post your entities mapping to COORDINATESLOCATION_INFORMATION and TEXTINFORMATION in particular the relationships?

Comment: Entities are added know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code you have provided, I can recreate the issue in EclipseLink . The generated script is;

```
CREATE TABLE COORDINATESLOCATION_INFORMATION (CoordinatesLocation_ID BIGINT 
NOT NULL, informationList_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY 
(CoordinatesLocation_ID, informationList_ID))
```

I have tried explicitly defining the columns of the join table;

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable (name = "COORDINATESLOCATION_INFORMATION",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CoordinatesLocation_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Information_ID",referencedColumnName = "ID" ))
private List<Information> informationList;
```

….but still get VARCHAR(255).

I have removed the

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

From the `Information` class (so defaulting to `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy) and this leads to the desired script:

```
CREATE TABLE COORDINATESLOCATION_INFORMATION (CoordinatesLocation_ID BIGINT NOT 
NULL, informationList_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (CoordinatesLocation_ID, 
informationList_ID)).
```

So, following that somewhat empirical analysis (I’m not sure why ID was mapped to type VARCHAR(255)) you have a couple of choices.

1. Modify you CREATE TABLE COORDINATESLOCATION_INFORMATION script to include informationList_ID BIGINT.
2. Change to @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType. SINGLE_TABLE). This requires the addition of a discriminator column and may not be in line with your approach.

Note also that with  @OneToMany you do not need a join table if you add a Foreign Key in your Information table and define @ManyToOne on the Information side and  @OneToMany on the CoordinatesLocation side with the `mappedBy` Attribute.

This link will give some idea of that. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence

Answer (score 0):

I can't read the localized message in your exception, however I'll guess that it says you can't compare bigint and varchar.  I'll further guess that the error is in this part of the SQL: `(t1.ID = t0.informationList_ID)`.  Is one of those columns a bigint and the other a varchar?

Comment: I used the datatype "Long" in every Entity. The ID is auto-generated.
I don't know which type t0.informationList_ID has because it was generated by JPA.

Comment: Oh ok. I see that t1.ID is BIG INT and t0.informationList_ID is VARCHAR.
But how could I say JPA to generate the assoziation-table with type BIGINT?

Comment: I don't know;  I've used JPA but I created my tables myself.  I haven't worked with EclipseLink's table creation.

Answer (score 0):

basically here t0.CoordinatesLocation_ID = ? at sometime your parameter is of type `BIGINT` and the reqested type is `VARCHAR`,  you should look at this